# Трейты в PHP

Tags: traits, php

Приведите пример хорошего решения использования трейтов в PHP. (или опишите ситуацию, когда решение использовать трейты будет оправданным или даже единственно правильным)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это отличная замена множественному наследованию. Рабочий пример - реализация "толстых" моделей - когда методы валидации формы выносятся в трейт и просто подключаются в модели.

Comment: Если ты еще и немного кода предложишь, то я скажу тебе спасибо и закрою этот вопрос.